# Can't figure out mod_rewrite with 2 parameters

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm building a website with PHP and trying to make RewriteRules.

There is a category page and it has a pagination.
Originally, the URL is like

```
/blog/category.php?category=2&page=2
```

And I want to redirect this as `/blog/category/2/page/2`

How can I make this work?

Only for category part, I tried the rules as

```
RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)$ category.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

but I couldn't figure out how to redirect the page part.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't expand your rewrite rule with the missing page parameter? Then you can access the page. There are a lot more possibilities but i think in your case it's the easiest way.

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/category/(\d+)/page/(\d+)$ category.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

And if you url includes `/blog` you should check if you need it in your rewrite rule.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However, it redirects me as /blog/category/1/page/1 and I clicked page 2, 3...then it leads me /blog/category/1/page/1/page/2/page/3... I think I made a mistake with the <a href...> part in html codes. Could you please tell me how I fix the part?

Comment: Current the part is like this. <a href='{$categoryId}/page/{$pagenum}'> and this code is in 'category.php' file.