# wrote mod_rewrite with 2 parameters but the URLs keep stacking

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

4 days ago, I asked this question.
[Can't figure out mod_rewrite with 2 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396352/cant-figure-out-mod-rewrite-with-2-parameters)

And I repeat the question below.

---

> I'm building a website with PHP and trying to make RewriteRules. There
>   is a category page and it has a pagination. Originally, the URL is
>   like
>
> ```
> /blog/category.php?category=2&page=2
> ```
>
> And I want to redirect this as `/blog/category/2/page/2`
>   How can I make this work?
>   (The values for category and page are passing through 'GET' method.)
>
> Only for category part, I tried the rules as
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)$ category.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
> ```
>
> but I couldn't figure out how to redirect the page part.

---

And I've got an answer, but it redirects me as `/blog/category/1/page/1` and the URLs keep stacking.
The first page works well, but then I click 2, 3.. the URL's like `/blog/category/1/page/1/page/2/page/3`...

The link for page part is like this.  `<a href='{$categoryId}/page/{$pagenum}'>`

I searched many answers but couldn't find like my case.
I think I make a very silly mistake but I can't figure this out.
Please, please, anyone help me.

Comment: From the look of it you want to make it work instead of redirecting.

Comment: Make sure to dynamically change the link of the pages of pagination.

Comment: @Saral  Thank you for the comments. I'm not sure about the 'dynamically change' but the link of the pages are set to be changed. They're in the 'for' statement, and they work fine without 'mod_rewrite'.

Comment: without 'mod_rewrite', the original link URLs were <a href='category.php?category={$categoryId}&page={$pagenum}'>. So I thought I made a mistake changing this part...

Comment: I mean the links of the pages of pagination should be changed to the link like you want such as `/blog/category/1/page/1`.

Comment: This article may help you to get rid of duplicate urls https://www.tinywebhut.com/remove-duplicate-urls-from-your-website-38

Comment: @Saral Thank you for your comment. And I read the article and it was clearly helpful but I couldn't find out my problem. T_T